# AngularJS : Change parent scope value from custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

For some reason I can't make this work based on the other examples I've seen here on SO.

Here's my directive:

```
(function () {

    angular.module('materialDesign')
        .directive('aSwitch', directive);

    function directive() {

        return {
            templateUrl: 'elements/material/switch/switch.html',
            transclude: false, // I've tried true here
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                enabled: '=',
                toggleState: '=',
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                element.on('click touchstart', function() {
                    scope.toggleState = !scope.toggleState;
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

And the controller scope value that I want to change when toggling the switch/checkbox:

```
$scope.hideInactive = true;
```

The html:

```
<a-switch toggle-state="hideInactive"></a-switch>
```

and further down in my html page, I have this:

```
<div ng-show="!hideInactive">
    <!-- stuff -->
</div>
```

EDIT:

This version is "working now", but as soon as I click my switch/checkbox a second time, the element.on fires twice, this flipping my scope value back to what it was.....basically, it's not letting me "un-check" my toggle.

```
angular.module('material')
    .directive('aSwitch', [
        '$timeout', function($timeout) {
            return {
                templateUrl: 'elements/material/switch/switch.html',
                transclude: false,
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    enabled: '=',
                    toggleState: '=',
                },
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    element.on('click touchstart', function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            scope.toggleState.state = !scope.toggleState.state;
                            scope.$apply();
                        });
                    });

                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

EDIT and FINAL SOLUTION:

Here's the updated directive link property that fixed everything. I'd like to add that Oleg Yudovich's answer was also used (passing an object as the property instead of a true/false by itself)

```
link: function (scope, element) {
                element.on('click touchstart', function (event) {
                    if (event.srcElement && event.srcElement.id && event.srcElement.id === "switch") {
                        event.stopPropagation();

                        $timeout(function() {
                            scope.toggleState.state = !scope.toggleState.state;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run digest cycle after changes in scope, because changing scope binding from event will not run angular digest cycle, you need to run it manually by doing `scope.$apply()`

**Directive**

```
(function () {

    angular.module('materialDesign')
        .directive('aSwitch', directive);

    function directive($timeout) {

        return {
            templateUrl: 'elements/material/switch/switch.html',
            transclude: false, // I've tried true here
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                enabled: '=',
                toggleState: '=',
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                element.on('click touchstart', function() {
                  $timeout(function(){
                    scope.toggleState = !scope.toggleState;
                  });
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: I've read calling the digest cycle specifically is bad, couldn't I just wrap the element.on portion in a $timeout?

Comment: @ganders using $timeout would be more safer to use .. because it will not conflict with currently running digest cycle..see my updates

Comment: i added the timeout (without the scope.$apply) around the element.on and  it started working......after waiting two minutes. Now I'll try it INSIDE the element.on.

Comment: @ganders that's my bad..code was not updated properly..you should not specify any time in timeout..the updated code will surely work

Comment: _it will not conflict with currently running digest cycle_ - There cannot be a running cycle when a DOM event is fired by the browser.

Comment: @zeroflagL `scope.$aaply()` was the correct solution then..just be sure about any conflict in digest cycle by using `$timeout`

Comment: See my edit above, now when I try to un-check my switch, the element.on fires twice, negating my un-check.

Comment: @ganders please remove `scope.$apply()` because you are already using `$timeout`

Comment: @ganders do you have two `a-switch` directive on same page? and where you are same value `hideInactive` to directive?

Comment: no, it only exists once. But, as I show in the html in the question, the property (hideInactive.state) is referenced in an ng-show also.

Comment: sorry, clicking twice (not necessarily double-clicking) made it go back to the original behavior. I'll try upping the timeout period...

Comment: event.stopPropogation()

Comment: @ganders that did the trick..?do you have any click event in child?

Comment: Ok, I believe I figured it out. My directive contains a lable, as well as an input. The click event was firing for both of those elements in my directive. If i just watch for the click on either the label, or the input, then I believe it should work. Once I get done with my testing, I'll update my question with the corrected code (and accept yours). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass object instead of primitive variable like this:

```
$scope.hideInactive = {
   state: false;
}
```

html without changes:

```
<a-switch toggle-state="hideInactive"></a-switch>
```

in your directive:

```
scope.toggleState.state = !scope.toggleState.state;
```

Reed this awesome article: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Please see my update (added the additional html section). I'm still working on getting this to work. (and also still reading your linked article)

Comment: Nothing changed here just a model instead variable: <div ng-show="!hideInactive.state">

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

```
angular.module('material').directive('aSwitch', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'elements/material/switch/switch.html',
        transclude: false,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            enabled: '=',
            toggleState: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('click touchstart', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.toggleState.state = !scope.toggleState.state;
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: $timeout will already trigger $apply when digest loop is completed.